# select all leaf nodes in sql tree

Tags: sql

Given a table (simplified):

```
CREATE TABLE tree
(
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    node_id INTEGER,
    parent INTEGER
)
```

Where `node_id` is id of the node, and `parent` is id of parent node. Root node has `id=0`.

How to find all "leaf" nodes, i.e. all nodes that is not a parent for any else node?

Answer (score 0):

Try a LEFT self `JOIN` and check for NULL values:

```
SELECT leaf.node_id
FROM tree AS leaf
LEFT OUTER JOIN tree AS child on child.parent = leaf.node_id
WHERE child.node_id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from tree t2 where t2.parent = t.node_id);
```

This is pretty equivalent to the `left join` method.  I just think that `not exists` is clearer about the intent of the query.